# oop in c++ (password generation)

Tags: c++, oop, password-generator

Object oriented programming in c++

I am learning oop in  c++ and cannot use oop for this problem. **oop** might not be the best solution for this
but I want in it. This question might be simple but i could not solve this it shows

```
**error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'char' in assignment**
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
class passwordGenerate{
private:
char letters[56];
int length;
char password[100];
public:
    passwordGenerate();
    void setLength(int);
    void setPassword(char p[]);
    void displayPassword();
};
passwordGenerate::passwordGenerate(){
  letters[56] = {'a','b','c','d','e',
                    'f','g','h','i','j',
                    'k','l','m','n','o',
                    'p','q','r','s','t',
                    'u','v','w','x','y','z',
                    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
                    '.','+','-','*','/',
                     '=','_',')','(','&',
                     '%','$','#','@','!',
                     '~',',','>','?','<'};
//it works when char letters[56] is given but does not work in this way.
}
void passwordGenerate::setLength(int l){
length = l;
}
void passwordGenerate::displayPassword(){
strcpy(password," ");
int random;
srand(time(0));
 for(int x =0 ;x<length;x++){
        random = rand()%55;
        password[x] = letters[random];
 }
 for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
 cout<<password[i];
 }
}


int main()
{
    passwordGenerate firstPassword;
    int length;
    cout<<"enter the length for password : ";
    cin>>length;
    firstPassword.setLength(length);
    firstPassword.displayPassword();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fwiw you can put the problematic code in `main` and you would get the same error. This is not related to OOP

Comment: is there a reason you are not using `std::string` instead of naked character arrays?

Comment: 1) This problem is not related to OOP. 2) Your example could be reduced to `int main () {char foo[56]; foo[56] = {'a', 'b'};}`, to reproduce the same issue, hence your example provided, isn't [mre] (emphasis on minimal).

Comment: `letters[56]` is just one character (at least it would be, if it existed). It’s not the entire array, and you can’t assign to arrays. Read more about arrays in your favorite C++ book.

Comment: This hardly has anything to do with OOP. OOP is not automatically triggered when you use a class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between `[]` in those two

```
int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
//    ^-----------------   size of the array

x[2] = 42;
//^---------------------   index of array element
```

So when you write

```
letters[56] = {'a',' .....
```

Then this is first accessing the array out of bounds (it has 56 elements and `letters[56]` is the 57-th). And you cannot assign `{'a',...` to a single `char` (type of elements).

To fix the problem I suggest you to work with `std::string` instead and use in-class initializer:

```
struct foo {
     std::string letters{"abcdefghijklmnop...."};
};
```

Last but not least, I would suggest to name that member `alphabet` rather than `letters`, because it is not only letters.

Comment: thank you @idclev for answer but can you clarify about strcut

Comment: @Phantasm what don't you understand about it?

Comment: what is meant by strcut  @idclev  I haven't heard this thing

Comment: @Phantasm sorry typo. It should be `struct`